# How to generate associated rule graph using python?

Tags: data-visualization

I am facing problems in order to implement the directed graphs of association rules.

Ex: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0GO3.png)

Ex code: plot(top10subRules, method = "graph",  engine = "htmlwidget")

Is there any kind of function in python that can generate this type of graphs like this way?